# How to connect DocumentDB and Laravel

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, laravel-5, aws-documentdb, aws-documentdb-mongoapi

I want to connect Laravel with DocumentDB from AWS.
But i cant find any document or tutorial about this.
is there a way to connect DocumentDB at least to Laravel server?

Comment: Rawelja, you should be able to connect to DocumentDB from Laravel using the same connection string and pre-requisites as MongoDB. Have had a chance to try the steps listed here: https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb. Happy to help you with any error/issues you have encountered

Answer (score 1):

The documentation provided in AWS [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/connect_programmatically.html) [for php] didn't work for me, the below connection uri works.

```
$dbUri = "mongodb://$user:$pass@$host:$port/$db?retryWrites=true&w=majority&authSource=admin
&ssl=true&sslcertificateauthorityfile=$sslFilePath/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem";
$client = new MongoDB\Client($dbUri,['readPreference' => 'secondaryPreferred']);
```

Comment: key difference is `sslcertificateauthorityfile`, usually its `ssl_ca_certs`.